# PsychoPy: Variable number of Image files in a TRIAL

Tags: python, psychopy

I would like to vary the number of images within a trial, for instance to have trials that contain 3 or 4 or 5...n images.

My Excel sheet contains two headers: "Span" and "Face". Span defines the number of trials that I want to have (e.g., 3,4...) and the Face contains the image file names (e.g., [F001.png,F002.png,F003.png] if Span is 3 or instance).

I created two loops, the inner loop (called trials) supposed to control the number of images within a trial, so the option 'Is trials' is unselected and the nReps option is linked to Span like $Span. The outer loop (trials_2) supposed to control the number of trials, hence, the 'Is trials' is selected and the nReps is set to 1.

However, I am unsure how to link the actual file names within the Image Properties, Image option.

I tried to add $Face, but it doesn't work.

If I use eval(Face)[trials.thisN], it provides me the following error message: Couldn't find image file'[';. So it tries to search for the first character of this row under the header Face.

I also tried to define my list as unicode "[F001.png,F002.png]" or '[F001.png,F002.png]' in the Excel file but none of the options work.

Does anybody have some suggestions?

```
# set up handler to look after randomisation of conditions etc
trials_2 = data.TrialHandler(nReps=1, method='sequential', 
    extraInfo=expInfo, originPath=-1,
    trialList=data.importConditions('Test001.xlsx'),
    seed=None, name='trials_2')
thisExp.addLoop(trials_2)  # add the loop to the experiment
thisTrial_2 = trials_2.trialList[0]  # so we can initialise stimuli with    some values
# abbreviate parameter names if possible (e.g. rgb=thisTrial_2.rgb)
if thisTrial_2 != None:
    for paramName in thisTrial_2.keys():
        exec(paramName + '= thisTrial_2.' + paramName)

for thisTrial_2 in trials_2:
    currentLoop = trials_2
    # abbreviate parameter names if possible (e.g. rgb = thisTrial_2.rgb)
    if thisTrial_2 != None:
        for paramName in thisTrial_2.keys():
            exec(paramName + '= thisTrial_2.' + paramName)

#     set up handler to look after randomisation of conditions etc
    trials = data.TrialHandler(nReps=Span, method='sequential', 
        extraInfo=expInfo, originPath=-1,
        trialList=data.importConditions('Test001.xlsx'),
        seed=None, name='trials')
    thisExp.addLoop(trials)  # add the loop to the experiment
    thisTrial = trials.trialList[0]  # so we can initialise stimuli with some values
    # abbreviate parameter names if possible (e.g. rgb=thisTrial.rgb)
    if thisTrial != None:
        for paramName in thisTrial.keys():
            exec(paramName + '= thisTrial.' + paramName)

    for thisTrial in trials:
        currentLoop = trials
        # abbreviate parameter names if possible (e.g. rgb = thisTrial.rgb)
        if thisTrial != None:
            for paramName in thisTrial.keys():
                exec(paramName + '= thisTrial.' + paramName)

        #------Prepare to start Routine "trial"-------
        t = 0
        trialClock.reset()  # clock 
        frameN = -1
        routineTimer.add(2.500000)
        # update component parameters for each repeat
        image.setImage(eval(Face)[trials.thisN])
        # keep track of which components have finished
        trialComponents = []
        trialComponents.append(image)
        trialComponents.append(text_2)
        for thisComponent in trialComponents:
            if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):
                thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED

        #-------Start Routine "trial"-------
        continueRoutine = True
        while continueRoutine and routineTimer.getTime() > 0:
            # get current time
            t = trialClock.getTime()
            frameN = frameN + 1  # number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
            # update/draw components on each frame

            # *image* updates
            if t >= 0.0 and image.status == NOT_STARTED:
                # keep track of start time/frame for later
                image.tStart = t  # underestimates by a little under one frame
            image.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
            image.setAutoDraw(True)
            if image.status == STARTED and t >= (0.0 + (2.0-win.monitorFramePeriod*0.75)): #most of one frame period left
                image.setAutoDraw(False)

        # *text_2* updates
            if t >= 2.0 and text_2.status == NOT_STARTED:
            # keep track of start time/frame for later
                text_2.tStart = t  # underestimates by a little under one frame
                text_2.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
                text_2.setAutoDraw(True)
            if text_2.status == STARTED and t >= (2.0 + (0.5-win.monitorFramePeriod*0.75)): #most of one frame period left
                text_2.setAutoDraw(False)

            # check if all components have finished
            if not continueRoutine:  # a component has requested a forced-end of Routine
                break
            continueRoutine = False  # will revert to True if at least one component still running
            for thisComponent in trialComponents:
                if hasattr(thisComponent, "status") and thisComponent.status != FINISHED:
                    continueRoutine = True
                    break  # at least one component has not yet finished

            # check for quit (the Esc key)
            if endExpNow or event.getKeys(keyList=["escape"]):
               core.quit()

            # refresh the screen
            if continueRoutine:  # don't flip if this routine is over or we'll get a blank screen
               win.flip()

        #-------Ending Routine "trial"-------
        for thisComponent in trialComponents:
            if hasattr(thisComponent, "setAutoDraw"):
                thisComponent.setAutoDraw(False)
    # completed Span repeats of 'trials'

    thisExp.nextEntry()

# completed 1 repeats of 'trials_2'

win.close()
core.quit()
```

Comment: Please extract a short section of the problematic code and include it with your question.

Comment: Thank you! I added the problematic part of the code.